# python working with xlsx sheets and files?

Tags: python

Python to export excel sheets into another workbook and save it to a directory ?

Comment: No. You need to write it yourself.

Comment: If your data is tabular, consider using pandas; `read_excel` and `to_excel` are pretty convenient.

Comment: It's not all tabular, because I want to move the charts to a different workbook too.  Copy won't work with this because copy doesn't copy charts.   VBA, you can just make a copy of the sheet to a different workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/). The are many examples and [tutorials](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/tutorial.html) available.